# Import/export in JavaScript gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, import, configuration, export, frontend

I have very simple question that I couldnt figure out for days. 
I have 2 .js files. One is for configuration. I need to call the data from default.js into app.js. But it gives
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I checked all online platforms to find a solution, tried all different combinations of export/import but could not find any solution.

//default.js

```
export default (config = {
  apiKey: "enterYourApiKeyFromOpenWeather"
});
```

//app.js

```
import config from "./config/default";
```

I am using vscode and  (import config from "./config/default";) line has underlined with underscores with space. I might need to install a package maybe.

If i write:

```
const config = require("./config/default");
```

I get this error:
app.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: jro, this is not a node.js project. it is vanilla javaScript.

Comment: oh i see, did you set `type=module` on your script element

Comment: both files are .js files.I believe  type=module   is used when u wanna export code in the html page inside the <script type=module> </script>

Comment: I think i was wrong with my previous comment. I did what u asked but didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify .js on your `default.js` import, since this is vanilla JS and not part of a build process (such as Gulp) or an `express.js` app per se.

In your `app.js`

```
import config from "./config/default.js";
```

When including your `app.js` in your script element, as mentioned by jro in the comments:

> ...did you set type=module on your script element – jro

You need to set `type=module` on your script AND your module, e.g.:

```
<script src="app.js" type="module">
<script src="config/default.js" type="module">
```

If you don't specify `type=module` you will run into `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` again.

Comment: I just did Caleb and i got new born errors: GET http://localhost:8000/config/default net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
default.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at default.js:1
(anonymous) @ default.js:1

Comment: Rewrite your default.js into this:

`export default config = {
  apiKey: "enterYourApiKeyFromOpenWeather"
};`

Remove the parentheses from your export,

On your import you need to import default as config since you don't have a named export, you are simply exporting default:

`import { default as config } from "./config/default.js";`

You can visit here for further reference: [http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html]

Comment: export default is a function. even I removed the parentheses, vscode automatically added them. i followed your instruction and i got another error:default.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at default.js:4 . I think issue might be with vscode itself. because i tried everything but nothing worked :(

Comment: Yeah you are not declaring a type for config. Try again with:

`const config = {
  apiKey: "enterYourApiKeyFromOpenWeather"
}`

And yes, keep the parentheses you are correct there.

So your default.js will look like:

`export default (const config = { apiKey: "enterYourApiKeyFromOpenWeather" });`

Comment: I got another error :( Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token const

Comment: Last attempt!

for your default.js

`const config = {apiKey: "enterYourApiKeyFromOpenWeather"};`

`export default config;`